# Validate на Laravel 5.4 username только английские буквы и цифры

Tags: auth, laravel5

Есть у меня сайт поднятый на Laravel 5.4

Я столкнулся проблемой, в том что при регистрации пользователя мне нужно разрешить имя пользователя **username** только на английских буквах и цифр.

У меня имеется код метод в контроллере.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'username' => 'required|string|without_spaces|max:255|unique:users',
        'email' => 'string|email|max:255|unique:users|nullable',
        'password' => 'string|min:6|confirmed|nullable',
    ]);
}
```

Есть какие нибудь соображения как можно это сделать? Я питался поставить в правилах **alpha_num** но дело не увенчалось успехом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае тебе необходимо использовать регулярное выражение, например

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'username' => 'required|string|without_spaces|max:255|regex:/^[a-z]+$/i|unique:users',
        'email' => 'string|email|max:255|unique:users|nullable',
        'password' => 'string|min:6|confirmed|nullable',
    ]);
}
```

Ну и тут конечно сам выбирай порядок применения правил слева направо. В данном случае регулярка стоит перед проверкой по username по базе, что не позволит совершить запрос к таблице пользователей, если поле не пройдет валидацию по предыдущим правилам.